# Create table with div, 2 fixed columns with same height all the time

Tags: html

I'd like a table created with DIV, this table has 2 fixed columns (that it's ok) but the both columns must have all the time the same height.

The code can be find here : [Code on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLeWA/)

**The code :**

```
<style type="text/css">     
    #container 
    { 
        position:relative; 
        width:100%; 
        margin:0 auto; 
    } 

    #header { 
        background-color:#5a7fa9; 
    } 

    #center { 
        overflow:hidden; 
        width:100%;         
    } 

    #left { 
        float:left; 
        width:200px; 
        background-color:Gray;
    } 

    #content { 
        margin-left:200px; 
        background-color:#a9bbd1; 
    } 

    #footer { 
        background-color:#95adc9; 
    } 
</style> 

<div id="container"> 
    <div id="header">header</div> 

    <div id="center"> 
        <div id="left">left</div> 
        <div id="content">content<br/><br/></div> 
    </div> 

    <div id="footer">footer</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

ther is an example

http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/dLeWA/9/

Comment: Javascript? That's cheap! +1 for solution :P

Comment: why it is a cheap.... it works fine in javascript and dynamically......
and code is valide :P

Comment: A javascript solution is nice, but don't forget to recalculate the height when it changes dynamically (e.g. the height of this answer will be heigher after adding this comment).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this dirty hack (only adding this css):

```
#center > div {
    margin-bottom: -2000px;
    padding-bottom: 2000px;
}
```

Also see your updated [example](http://jsfiddle.net/dLeWA/6/).

=== UPDATE ===

I'll try to explain it:
The `padding-bottom` uses the `background-color`. It has to be a heigh value (the minimum different height between the lowest and heighest column). So each column in the center-div add the background-color at the bottom. The negative `margin-bottom` sets the height back to it's real height. (The entire content is also be visible, even if the minimum height isn't large enough.)

Comment: can you please explain your answer so that we understand what this dirty hack gonna play with our style sheets..

Comment: @scessor +1 for an explanation :)

Comment: this seems like a bad strategy in the long run :S

Answer (score 0):

Hi i would like to explain the answer given by Howdy_McGee ..

Add `min-height: 100px` to `#center`

Add `height: 100%` to `#left`

Add `height: 100%` to `content`

he explained the above change which is completely correct.

Seeing your code in jiddle you havent wrote height anywhere in your css style. Therefore all your containers will take `height:auto` as per the content into it.

you have a `div` with `id='center'` this div should have some min-height:100px; and both the inner container should have `height:100%` by this your elements inside the `center` div will take height of their parent.

I had preferred you to give the `min-height:100px` because incase you are putting in dynamic content inside your inner boxes `height` should increase automatically, therefore if you do not have any content into your div `height` will stick to `100px`.

Hope my explanation makes sense because i am in a bit hurry to type.

Comment: With `min-height: 100px` the `background-color` don't fill the columns (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLeWA/10/)).

Comment: `min-height` is a strange beast

Comment: i am wrong in my explanation. i accept the mistake, it made me learn something from this, or i would have just assumed i was right in my theory.